# Bootstrap 4 navbar links don't show in collapse

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

Everything works as it should until the navbar collapses. After collapse the links disappear. I've gone over the Bootstrap examples and documentation, but can't see where my issue is.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top bg-dark navbar-dark py-1">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="py-2 navbar-brand" href="#">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="d-block mx-auto" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false"><title>Product</title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><path d="M14.31 8l5.74 9.94M9.69 8h11.48M7.38 12l5.74-9.94M9.69 16L3.95 6.06M14.31 16H2.83m13.79-4l-5.74 9.94"></path></svg>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Tour</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Product</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Enterprise</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Support</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Dashboard</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="{% url 'landingpage:register' %}">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import boostrap.js and jquery.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was reading through my own question I realized I had made a, now obvious, mistake. Instead of deleting the question I'm posting the answer in case someone else searching may have overlooked a `display property` leftover from a previous iteration.

`d-none` was mistakenly left within the link tags. [Display Property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) classes can be very handy to hide elements on different display sizes. However, `d-none` will hide an element in any size. In my case, combined with `d-md-inline-block` allowed the links to be displayed prior to collapse, but after collapse `d-none` took over and hid the links.

As stated in the [Bootstrap 4 docs on Display Properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) (which I apparently overlooked in my search);

*"To hide elements simply use the .d-none class or one of the .d-{sm,md,lg,xl}-none classes for any responsive screen variation.
To show an element only on a given interval of screen sizes you can combine one .d-x-none class with a .d-x-x class, for example .d-none .d-md-block .d-xl-none will hide the element for all screen sizes except on medium and large devices."*